# How to share variable in before and after each run in jest?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

In `beforeEach` I am seeding my db. There is ID (is created on server side). I need to clean my db in `afterEach`. How can I share this variable? Is safe to store in some global context?

```
describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const ID = axios.post(...)
    });

    afterEach(async()=> { 
        axios.delete(ID)
    });

    it('....', () => {
        // test
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be shared between tests by just placing then outside of the `describe` function scope as follows:

```
const ID = axios.post(...)

describe(...
```

*I would additionally recommend to mock out the axios post and work with mock values exclusively as relying on outside services in unit tests is an anti-pattern.*